# Can an externally loaded mobile app be contained within another mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, air

If you create a mobile app which uses  a custom url scheme to launch an external app, can that external app be visually contained within your mobile app? I want to launch a skype window, but have the tabs, borders, etc. of my mobile app (which happens to be an AIR app, but for which I could create a native extension) still visible, so that the skype window is one of the views within the app.

A corollary: can one get the position and size of the launched application window? If so it might be possible at least to create the illusion that skype (or any other launched app, for that matter) is contained within your mobile app.

Comment: Depends on if the makers of the external app allow for it via intents/APIs/etc. For your Skype example, I don't think they do. For something like Google Maps, it has an available API to do that.

Comment: for iOS, it is not possible. the only thing you can do is using their API (if there is one) to make something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** possible in iOS 6.

---

*There is a possibility, that launching other apps and displaying their views just like you described, may find its way to public SDK in future versions. Now only system components can do this.*

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but it does seem to be correct.  If someone can add something about android, please do.